# logrotate - no such file or directory

Tags: cron, logrotate

Every morning I wake up to this e-mail from the Cron Daemon:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error accessing /var/log/ejabberd: No such file or directory
error: ejabberd:1 glob failed for /var/log/ejabberd/*.log
error: found error in /var/log/ejabberd/*.log , skipping
```

How do I stop it? There is indeed no such file or directory, so why is it trying to do something there? I uninstalled ejabberd a long time ago.

Comment: For my future knowledge, was it in `/etc/logrotate.d`?

Comment: Yes, thanks to your answer, I found the existence of `/etc/logrotate.d/ejabberd` and wiped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point ejabberd must have created a logrotate file to rotate its logs. The daily logrotate job, scheduled in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, reads any job configuration files in `/etc/logrotate.d` and the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file, and actions the instructions in them. As there is no `/var/log/ejabberd` directory, the daily logrotate job reports outputs an error.

As mentioned in [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/876397/320386) any output from a cron job is sent in an email to the recipient in the `MAILTO` variable.

To permanently disable this behaviour, the logrotate job for ejabberd should be stopped. Look in `/etc/logrotate.d` for the ejabberd file, remove it with:

```
sudo rm /etc/logrotate.d/ejabberd
```